# Ender 3 Pro, Motherboard v4.2.7, Marlin 2.0.1 Firmware reset

Tags: marlin, firmware

Upgrading motherboard to v4.2.7   How do I reset the firmware after making wrong mods?

Answer (score 2):

You could download the firmware version [directly from the vendor](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/pages/firmware-download) and choose [the one](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W3Ed91h_GtFX0gpw1lHDAy3wYvpkzEmG) that is supposed to be on the board when it was shipped to you.

Put the bin file on the SD card from your laptop/computer and reinsert the SD card in the printer and start the printer.